# Cypress Component Testing for Angular stub child components

Tags: angular, cypress, angular-test, cypress-component-test-runner

I have a component composed of two very complicated child components.  I have developed and tested both children using cypress component testing (angular) and they pass.
Now I want to work on the parent component in isolation of its children.  The code for the parent is as follows:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-parent',
    template: `
        <main>
            <app-child-1></app-child-1>
            <app-child-2></app-child-2>
        </main>
        <footer>
            <button [disabled]= child1Form.valid && child2From.valid>Submit</button>
        </footer>`,
    styleUrls: [],
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild(Child1Component) child1Component: Child1Component = {} as Child1Component;
    @ViewChild(Child2Component) child2Component: Child2Component = {} as Child2Component;

    ngOnInit() { /* ... */ }
}
```

in my test:

```js
cy.mount(ParentComponent,{
   declarations: [Child1Component, Child2Component]
})
```

I am hoping to use `cy.stub` somehow to "copy" the children. Other thoughts also welcomed.

Comment: Did you find a solution? If yes, please post it here.